# htaccess: how to redirect all pages to a holding page

Tags: .htaccess

I have to put a site down for about half an hour while we put a second server in place. Using .htaccess, how can I redirect ANY request to `domain.com` to `domain.com/holding_page.php`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding_page.php$ 

RewriteRule $ /holding_page.php$l [R=307,L]
```

Use 307 (thanks [Piskvor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19746/piskvor)!) rather than 302 - [307 means](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The requested resource resides
>   temporarily under a different URI.
>   Since the redirection MAY be altered
>   on occasion, the client SHOULD
>   continue to use the Request-URI for
>   future requests.

Comment: This seems to work

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/indexTEMP.php$ 

RewriteRule $ /indexTEMP.php [R=307,L]

Comment: As this answer still comes up top in search results, it might be a good idea to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]`. This stops images breaking through redirecting them to the holding page. I know it wasn't strictly part of the original question - but handy nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

As I came across this problem, here is the solution I used (brief explanations in the comments):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not redirect when using your IP if necessary
# edit to match your IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.1\.1\.1

# do not redirect certain file types if necessary
# edit to match the file types needed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css)

# this holding page that will be shown while offline
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/offline\.html$

# use 503 redirect code during the maintenance job
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /offline.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /offline.html

# bots should retry accessing your page after x seconds
# edit to match your maintenance window
Header always set Retry-After "3600"

# disable caching
Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"
```

Besides the additional conditions and headers, the main idea is to **use a `503` status code** when you are doing a maintenance job.

The `503` code stands for `Service Unavailable`, which is exactly the case during the maintenance. Using this will also be SEO friendly as the bots won't index the `503` pages, and they will come back later-on after the specified `Retry-After` to look for the actual content.

Read more details here:

- Use a 503 HTTP status code (from a person who worked at Google) - https://plus.google.com/+PierreFar/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB
- Redirect Site to Maintenance Page using Apache and HTAccess - http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Redirect-Site-to-Maintenance-Page-using-Apache-and-HTAccess
- HTTP 503: Handling site maintenance correctly for SEO - https://yoast.com/http-503-site-maintenance-seo/

Answer (score -3):

This works better...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding_page.php$ 
RewriteRule $ /holding_page.php [R=307,L]
```