# Redirect All Requests to a Post

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all pages to a blog post at URL
example.com/big-changes-for-2013/
(including trailing slash)

I do not want to redirect me, because I'm working on the rest of the site.
This is what I have so far (this is a .htaccess redirect):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/big-changes-for-2013/$ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.137\.88\.129
RewriteRule $ /big-changes-for-2013/$ [R=302,L]
```

The part preventing me from being redirected works. The part thats not working is the redirect itself, which is an infinite loop.

The code above is based off of a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361933/htaccess-how-to-redirect-all-pages-to-a-holding-page) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522921/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-single-page).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.137\.88\.129
RewriteRule ^(?!big-changes-for-2013/$) /big-changes-for-2013/$ [R=302,L]
```

The rule regexp is what is a called a negative look-ahead assertion.  It means "match anything other than `big-changes-for-2013/$`".

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^50\.137\.88\.129
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(big-changes-for-2013/)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /big-changes-for-2013/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```